# Can I set VARCHAR size larger than 8k but less than MAX?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Starting in SQL 2005, VARCHAR(MAX) is no longer limited to 8000 bytes, it instead can go up to 2GB using "overflow" pages.

But what if I want to limit this column to say, 10k bytes?  It seems I get an error if I try to put anything in the size parameter above 8000.  Which is odd because MAX is the same as asking for a 2GB limit.  Seems like its a sort of "all or nothing" when it comes to the Max size.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can, but it requires you to implement a CHECK constraint:

```
CHECK (DATALENGTH([VarChar10000]) <= 10000)
```

Reference:

- [SQL SERVER – 2005 Constraint on VARCHAR(MAX) Field To Limit It Certain Length](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/01/sql-server-2005-constraint-on-varcharmax-field-to-limit-it-certain-length/)

Answer (score 9):

No you can not.
either varchar(<=8000) or varchar(MAX), nothing in between.

You can do this though:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VarChar10000] ( [VarChar10000] VARCHAR(MAX) )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VarChar10000] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [MaxLength10000]
    CHECK (DATALENGTH([VarChar10000]) <= 10000)
GO
```

Check [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/faq/sql-server-2005-varchar-max-p01.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you cannot do this [directly].  It is either 0-8000 or MAX.

Attempt to using say 10000 will give:

```
The size (10000) given to the type 'varchar' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).
```

You can however use a VARCHAR(MAX) column with a CHECK contraint.  Something like:

```
CHECK (DATALENGTH([myBigColumn]) <= 10000)
```